# Is it possible to underline text without HTML syntax in Quarto?

Tags: text, syntax, quarto

I was wondering if it is possible to underline text without HTML syntax in `Quarto`? You can strikethrough the text using `~~` syntax like this:

```
~~mytext~~
```

Output:

[image]

So I was wondering if it is possible to underline your text with somehow similar syntax like above?

Comment: @shafee, My bad! I mean underline of course ;)

Comment: Actually, the question is whether markdown supports it.

Comment: Master @shafee, you are right. Do you know if there is maybe a fancy CSS option instead of HTML?

Comment: Again, I am really baffled why are you calling me master? : )

Comment: @shafee, Because you know a lot about Quarto and Rmarkdown, that's why!

Comment: Honestly, All I do using the search engine `google` and thanks to the quarto Devs, they have documented everything very nicely. Really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want just to use css, you may try the following,

```
---
format: html
---

## Quarto

[This text is underlined]{style="text-decoration: underline;"}
```

---

[image: underlined text]

---

But the above approach will only work for html output format. If you want to get underlined text for html, pdf or docx output, try the following syntax, (which is handled by the pandoc itself)

```
---
format: html # pdf or docx
---

## Quarto

[This text is underlined]{.underline}
```

Comment: @Quinten, see the updated answer, which is I think a better approach.